# NSTask completion

Tags: javascript, objective-c, automation, osx-yosemite, osascript

How do I provide a callback to know when a task has completed? Do I need to set up an NSRunLoop or something?

```
ObjC.import('Cocoa');

exec("/usr/bin/say",["hello"])
function done(notification) {
    $.NSLog('Application done');
    $.NSLog(notification);
}
function exec(cmd,args){
    var task = $.NSTask.alloc.init
    task.launchPath=cmd
    task.arguments=args
    task.terminationHandler = $(done) // does not work!
    task.launch
    $.NSLog("running: "+task.running)
    return task
}
```

PS The language is JavaScript for Automaton, a new OSASCRIPT language for Yosemite OS X 10.10

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you have tried this, but maybe is worth it to give it a shot and see if it works for you..

I think, you could try using one of these two functions.. as `$.performSelector...` and see if it works for you..

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myTask) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

[self performSelector:@selector(myTask) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

I hope it helps..

Comment: Your code is written in actual Objective-C. I am writing in JavaScript for Automaton.

Comment: yah, but I see that you are still using Objective-C classes..So, I'm guessing if you access to the classes you should have access to the member functions as well.

Comment: I’ve never written in Objective-C. I’ve seen many demos on the net. 
There is so little about JFA or how to deal with the objc classes.

I have synchronous code working, but I am an asynchronous guy coming from a node.js world.